# How to extract multiple .7z files with password? (GUI preferred)

Tags: 12.04, 7zip

I have lots of .7z files, all with the same password. How can I extract them all easily? The default GUI in Ubuntu 12.04 is asking for the password for each file, which is too slow and annoying.

Comment: Related: [7z cli: Extract multiple files with same password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168640/7z-cli-extract-multiple-files-with-same-password)

Answer (score 3):

Not a GUI solution but command line:

```
find . -name *.7z -type f| xargs -I {} 7z x -ppassword {}
```

Where -ppassword means that "password" is your password.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the command-line tools or install packages such as `p7zip-full`, perhaps the best program for you would be [Peazip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/peazip-linux.html), although it is not in the repositories. Choose the GTK 2 version from the [Sourceforge link](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/peazip-linux.html) and install the `deb` file with `gdebi` or `software center`. There is also a 'portable' version that you can download, extract and then run the executable without installing it.

Its handling of `.7z` files is good, and it has support for password protected files, which is exactly what you want, and several other useful tools, such as one to check the integrity of archives and even one to benchmark the time taken to compress/decompress files.

It has support for extracting many files at once, as you see in the first screenshot; in the second screenshot you can see the simple, file-manager like GUI, which makes it simple to select the archives to be extracted.

[image]
[image]