# 7z cli: Extract multiple files with same password

Tags: 7zip

My filelist in work dir:

```
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [01][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [02][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [03][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [04][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [06][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [07][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [08][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [09][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [10][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [11][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [12][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [13][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [14][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [15][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [16][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [17][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [18][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [19][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [20][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [21][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [22][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [23][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'[CASO] SHIROBAKO [24][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar'
'Daisan Hikou Shoujotai.rar'
 Exodus.rar
 passwd.txt
 Scans.rar
 SPs.part1.rar
 SPs.part2.rar
 SPs.part4.rar
```

I try to use 7z extract above *.rar files:

```
7z e *.rar -oOPT -p$(cat passwd.txt) -r
```

but result:

```
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 864186364 bytes (825 MiB)

Extracting archive: [CASO] SHIROBAKO [01][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar
--
Path = [CASO] SHIROBAKO [01][Ma10p_1080p][x265_2flac].rar
Type = Rar
Physical Size = 864186364
Solid = -
Blocks = 2
Multivolume = -
Volumes = 1


No files to process
Everything is Ok

Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 864186364
```

That seems does not work.
I feel confused.

Comment: What about using `find . -iname "*.rar" -exec 7z e {} -oOPT -p$(cat passwd.txt) \;` ?

Comment: Hi @Michal Przybylowicz : Thanks your reply. This work fine. But I also want to know why My command can't.

Comment: I also try ```find . -iname "*.rar" -exec 7z x {} -oOPT -p$(cat passwd.txt) -r +```, but I got the error report ```find: missing argument to `-exec'``` . Why ```+``` can't.

Comment: You can try to use double quotes like this `7z e "*.rar" -oOPT -p$(cat passwd.txt)`.

Comment: Hi @Michal Przybylowicz: ```7z e "*.rar" -oOPT -p$(cat passwd.txt)``` is work fine. Could you post it to answer? Thanks!

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Yeah, for some reason, `7z` doesn't look at the `-p` option when multiple filename arguments are given--but unlike the overwhelming majority of commands on a Unix-like system, it does its own interpretation of globs like `*.rar` to specify multiple files, and when run with one such argument, it does respect `-p`. Either single or double quotes are fine here, as both prevent the shell from expanding `*.rar` into multiple arguments to `7z`. Since you came up with the solution, I recommend posting an answer about it, as curlywei suggested.

Comment: Or use ```\*.rar``` also can work fine same to ```"*.rar"```

Comment: I have posted an answer without the `-r` flag since the manual says `Do not use "-r" because this flag does not do what you think.` Unfortunately it does not explain what it actually does.

Comment: Hi @ Michal Przybylowicz: I look this manual for 7z option -r: ```-r: Enable recurse subdirectories.```. Yes, ``` this flag does not do what you think.```. Thanks your mentions.

Comment: Manual website: sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/recurse.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put double quotes around the `*.rar` part of the command :

```
7z e "*.rar" -oOPT -p$(cat passwd.txt)
```